# Can we use QGIS for Image Annotation?

Tags: qgis-plugins, geotiff-tiff, annotation

Can we use QGIS for Image Annotation? Box or Polygon Labelling? Can someone suggest any tool for the same? The file format is tiff.

I aim to find out copper sites in multiband tiff images. I have used sentinel 2a data. Combined the 12 bands into a raster and exported it as a tiff file.

I want to label the mine location in tiff file using an annotation tool.

So far I have tried

1. http://emapr.ceoas.oregonstate.edu/pages/education/how_to/image_segmentation/how_to_spatial_segmentation.html - scikit-learn to do this although as the size of my tiff file is 3 GB. This fails to do the work.
2. I am currently tring AWS but I am not sure it is processes tiff files.
3. GRASS/QGIS - I know it performs Supervised Learning, although I am not sure if it has any plugin for annotation.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're aiming at? What have you researched and tried so far?

Comment: Sure, I am editing the question.

Comment: What is wrong with creating a shapefile and marking each mine by a feature?

Comment: Is there any information loss when we convert tiff to shapefile? Also are shapefiles supported by Python.

Comment: You can't convert tiff to shapefile.

Comment: Take a look at https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/WxGUI_Supervised_Classification_Tool